# Can no longer SSH to my AWS EC2 instance - Operation timed out error

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using the following command to SSH into my AWS EC2 server and this has been working fine for some time, however recently it hangs and then times out.

```
ssh -i "ec2-pro-clubs-server.pem" ubuntu@ec2-35-178-119-142.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com -vT

OpenSSH_9.0p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/username/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to ec2-35-178-119-142.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com port 22.
ssh: connect to host ec2-35-178-119-142.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Operation timed out
```

The server itself is still operational and i've not changed any SSH keys locally so not sure why this would always time out? Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: A timeout is a connectivity issue. There might be a firewall blocking these connections or sshd is not listening at all.